# Obtaining the clicked value from a table cell in an text input

Tags: javascript, cell

I have a table with 6 COLS and 12 ROWS. In the first column is a filed with dimensions (4 ml) and in the other 5 columns are the prices with are different one from another.

What I like to do is when I click on a cell from the table to autocomplete below 2 inputs 1 with dimension and another with the price from that cell.

I've manage to do the first part but the second one I don't know how to do. Please have a look at my code below:

```
<script>
(function () {
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onclick', run);
}

function run() {
    var t = document.getElementById('myTable');
    t.onclick = function (event) {
        event = event || window.event; //IE8
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { // find TR
            target = target.parentElement;
        }
        //if (!target) { return; } //tr should be always found
        var cells = target.cells; //cell collection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td'); //alternative

        var f1 = document.getElementById('Inaltime / Dimensiune');
        var f2 = document.getElementById('Ø');
        f1.value = cells[0].innerHTML;
        f2.value = cells[1].innerHTML, cells[2].innerHTML;
        //console.log(target.nodeName, event);
    };
}

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your above code is working till f1.value, but if it does and if you are checking for only f2.value then this is what you have to do

```
 f2.value = cells[1].innerHTML + ',' + cells[2].innerHTML;
```

Comment: It work but in my input i want only the value that is clicked for, and when i click on another value to put that value in my text input not both values!

Comment: so what if the user clicks on first column that is dimensions columns. What value do you want to display on the second input box?

Comment: The dimension box value. [Take a look here this is the table that i want to modify](http://coșdefum.ro/tarife-si-preturi.php)